# sas format 1,000 to 1k

Tags: format, sas

How to use picture format to do this?

(1234 -> 1.2k, 1735 -> 2.0k, 888 -> 0.9k, 100 -> 0.1k)

I attempt to use the below code but it doesn't work.

```
proc format;
 picture InK (round)
  0 - 999 = '009.9 k' (mult=.001)
  1e3 - 9999 = '09k' (mult=.001)
  1e4 - 1e5 = '00.99k' (mult=.001);
run;
```

Comment: Why is 1735 formatted as 2.0k, when all the others are rounded correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SAS does the multiplication first and then overlays the template.  The overlay isn't really a math operation, it's just inserting a decimal point between the two rightmost digit.  You need to multiply by a factor of 10 less.

```
proc format;
 picture InK (round) low - high = '9.9k' (mult=.01);
run;
```

This is pretty confusing to me, but is consistent with the SAS [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a002473467.htm#a003281544).

Comment: That's because picture is not really using a number post-multiplication: it takes the left-of-decimal part and treats it as text (discarding the part after the decimal).